# Differenza tra "si mette" e "si mise"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, difference

So che `mettersi a fare qualcosa` si dice `put oneself doing something`.

Recentemente, ho incontrato il verbo `si mise` nella frase `...quasi feriva gli occhi, lui si mise a pensare alla morte` e mi pare che significhi lo stesso che `si mette`.

Mi potete dire che differenza c'è tra le due parole ?

Comment: «“mettersi a fare qualcosa” si dice [in inglese] “put oneself doing something”»: sei sicuro? L'inglese non è la mia prima lingua, ma io direi più qualcosa come “to start doing something”.

Comment: Mi sono permesso qualche piccola correzione all'italiano della domanda.

Comment: Sono un po' confuso dalla domanda. Usi correttamente i tempi verbali, per cui immagino tu sia al corrente della differenza tra il [presente e il passato remoto](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tempi-verbali_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/). Forse è il fatto che *mise* è un passato remoto irregolare che ti confonde?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Io ho subito pensato che il dubbio provenisse del fatto che l'OP non avesse identificato la forma "mise" come il passato remoto di "mettere".

Comment: Si tratta di una frase del romanzo *Sostiene Pereira* di Antonio Tabucchi?

Comment: si esattamente grazie, l'ho visto `si mise` tra poco nella coniugazione del verbo `mettersi`, in passato remoto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La differenza è che "si mette" è presente indicativo, mentre "si mise" è passato remoto del verbo "mettersi", come si può vedere in questa [tabella di coniugazione del verbo "mettere"](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=mettere).

Si tratta di una frase del romanzo *Sostiene Pereira* di Antonio Tabucchi:

> Quel bel giorno d’estate, con la brezza atlantica che accarezzava le cime degli alberi e il sole che splendeva, e con una città che scintillava, letteralmente scintillava sotto la sua finestra, e un azzurro, un azzurro mai visto, sostiene Pereira, di un nitore che quasi feriva gli occhi, lui si mise a pensare alla morte.

È una frase con un verbo dichiarativo al presente ("sostiene"), ma il resto della frase, che esprime quello che "Pereira sostiene", è al passato (Pereira riferisce fatti passati). Quindi, nella parte della frase riportata nella domanda, c'è da aspettarsi un verbo al passato e non al presente.

Comment: grazie tanto Charo

Comment: Solo una piccola nota: verbo “al” passato e non “al” presente.

Comment: @Benedetta si, grazie.

Comment: Correzione fatta: grazie mille, @Benedetta!

Comment: Prego, @Charo, figurati!